Ingress is not working on my Kubernetes clusters
Note: This question is copied from stackoverflow because I got an advise about question portal.
I have built Kubernetes clusters that consists of four nodes.
But ingress is not reachable from control plane or deployed host.
I tried to deploy services by NodePort then the service is reachable from any node IPs.
My ingress is deployed specific IP address so my Kubernetes is works fine so that I consider my network config has something wrong but I'm not sure.
I have checked following health connection.

pod to service: OK
pod to ingress: Connection refused
control plane to deployed ip address with port: Connection refused

Application config for each nodes:
ufw allow k8s-worker k8s-calico
ufw allow in vxlan.calico
ufw allow out vxlan.calico
ufw allow k8s-pods from 192.168.0.60/30
ufw allow k8s-nginx-ingress from 192.168.0.60/30

Detail application config:
# For control plane
[k8s-cp]
title=Kubernetes for control plane
description=Kubernetes for control plane
ports=80,443,2379,2380,6443,10250:10252,10259,10257,30000:32767/tcp

# For worker node
[k8s-worker]
title=Kubernetes for worker node
description=Kubernetes worker node
ports=80,443,10250,30000:32767/tcp

# Common config
[k8s-calico]
title=callico
description=callico for kubernetes CNI
ports=47,179/tcp|4789/udp|2379/tcp

[k8s-pods]
title=Kubernetes Pods Communication
description=Allow traffic from Kubernetes pods within the CIDR range.
ports=1:65535/tcp|1:65535/udp

[k8s-nginx-ingress]
title=Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller
description=Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller
ports=8443/tcp

Deployments:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: nginx-test
  labels:
    name: nginx-test
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: nginx-test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:1.14.2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "0.1"
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "0.1"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  namespace: nginx-test
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: nginx

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-test
  namespace: nginx-test
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nginx-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
      host: sparrow03.local

The ingress status:
Name:             ingress-test
Labels:           app=nginx
Namespace:        nginx-test
Address:          192.168.0.63
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host             Path  Backends
  ----             ----  --------
  sparrow03.local  
                   /   nginx-service:8080 (172.16.184.3:80,172.16.214.3:80)
Annotations:       nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                   From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                  ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    4m12s (x3 over 5m3s)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync

There is a specification of each node.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Kubernetes: 1.29.3
CRI: containerd
CNI: Calico
Ingress class: nginx
Hardware: Raspberry Pi 4

